# how to Set dropdownlist selected value in Edit page MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

How to set DropdownList selected item in the Edit page?.
What code should I write in DropdownList instead of "Nothing"

[image: ِDebuge mode - picture 1]

[image: Debuge mode - picture 2]

[image: List View that showing 1 Row - picture 3]

[image: Edit view page with DDL - picture 4]

This is Controler:

```
' GET: MachinInfo/Edit/5
Function MachinInfoEdit(ByVal id As Integer?) As ActionResult
    If IsNothing(id) Then
        Return New HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
    End If
    Dim machinInfo As MachinInfo = db.MachinInfo.Find(id)
    If IsNothing(machinInfo) Then
        Return HttpNotFound()
    End If
    ViewBag.BrandID = New SelectList(db.Brand, "Id", "BrandName")

    Return View(machinInfo)
End Function

' POST: MachinInfo/Edit/5
<HttpPost()>
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
Function MachinInfoEdit(<Bind(Include:="Id,PelakStateID,MachinStateID,OrgCode,MachineID,BrandID,MachintypeID,NPlate,NPlateL,NPlateM,NPlateR,CardSerial,VIN,Myear,Color,GearTypeID,MCost,Mcamp,Description,LogI,LogE")> ByVal machinInfo As MachinInfo) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then

        db.Entry(machinInfo).State = EntityState.Modified
        db.SaveChanges()
        Return RedirectToAction("Index")
    End If
    ViewBag.BrandID = New SelectList(db.Brand, "Id", "BrandName")

    Return View(machinInfo)
End Function
```

and my Edit View:

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.BrandID, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("BrandID", Nothing, "-select-", htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "form-control"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.BrandID, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`SelectList` overload with 4 parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_System_String_System_String_System_Object_) and pass selected value as the last parameter:

```
ViewBag.BrandID = New SelectList(db.Brand, "Id", "BrandName", id.ToString())
ViewBag.DefaultBrand = id.ToString()
```

Then pass ViewBag contents into `DropDownList` helper with `DirectCast` or `TryCast`:

```
@Html.DropDownList("BrandID", TryCast(ViewBag.BrandID, SelectList), ViewBag.DefaultBrand, htmlAttributes := New With { .class = "form-control"})
```

**Side note:**

Better to create a viewmodel property which has `SelectList` or `IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)` type -

```
Public Class ViewModel
    ' other properties

    Public Property SelectedBrandID As Integer
    Public Property BrandList As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)
End Class
```

Then populate it inside controller action:

```
Dim model As New ViewModel
model.BrandList = db.Brand.[Select](Function(x) New SelectListItem() With {
                          .Text = x.Id, 
                          .Value = x.BrandName,
                          .Selected = If(x.Id = id, True, False) }))

Return View(model)
```

And finally use `DropDownListFor` helper to show option lists:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.BrandID, Model.BrandList, Nothing, htmlAttributes := New With { .class = "form-control"})
```

Related issue:

[MVC.NET in VB - Select List to Html.Dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290322/mvc-net-in-vb-select-list-to-html-dropdownlist)

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I implemented first offer, but the problem did not resolve. When the page is loaded, it still displays  **"-select-"**.

Comment: Try remove the `"-select-"` part and change it with `Nothing` - then the placeholder should be changed by assigned value inside `SelectList`.

Comment: I replaced it with `Nothing`, but this time it appears on the first list option, which is not correct. i attached screenshot of debugging mode, Please see it

Comment: It is necessary to assign fourth parameter of `SelectList` with a value which exist inside `DataValueField` to mark default selected item - you can get passed ID and use `ToString()` to set it.

Comment: Adding `id.Tostring`, the problem of passing `id` was fixed. But `DropDownList` still displays on the first list item, which is not correct - i added second screenshot

Comment: Can you provide example image what currently the DDL looks like and the expected option list to explain mentioned *first list item*, are you want to display selected value as first option list?

Comment: I added pictures 3 and 4 . As shown in Figure 3, which is related to the list, in pic4, `J` must be selected in the DDL not `A`.